# Hibernate Found shared references to a collection

Tags: hibernate

EDIT - I have simplified this post to reproduce the problem with a single set

I have upgraded hibernate from 4.3.11 to 5.2.8 and am now getting a shared reference exception. Various related posts I have read dont seem to help.

My db tables are
[image]

These tables are used to represent "things" and "Things owned by things". e.g. Person owns house/s, houses own computer/s, computers own components. Etc All recursive sets of 'Master' to their 'Asset'. This worked perfectly prior to hibernate v5.

MasterAsset.hbm.xml as follows

```
...
<many-to-one name="master" class="mypath.Master" fetch="select">
    <column name="MASTER_ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>

<many-to-one name="asset" class="mypath.Master" fetch="select">
    <column name="MST_ASSET_ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
...

<set name="masterAssetLinkedToAsset" table="MASTER_ASSET" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key column="MASTER_ID" property-ref="asset"/>
    <one-to-many class="mypath.MasterAsset"/>
</set>
```

MasterAsset.java contains

```
  private Set<MasterAsset> masterAssetLinkedToAsset = new HashSet<MasterAsset>(0);
  private Master master;
  private Master asset;
```

All I do to get this problem is

```
creteria.list(MasterAsset)
```

which gives me this error :

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:91)
    ... 
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: mypath.domain.MasterAsset.masterAssetLinkedToAsset
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:56)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: mypath.domain.MasterAsset.masterAssetLinkedToAsset
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:104)
```